# autoplot() from OpenStreetMap map masked by geom_point() layer

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I am trying to overlap points (from dataframe `df`) on an open street map tile. The layer with the points is although masking the OpenStreetMap map tile

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(tidyverse)

map <- openmap(c(lat = 46.2037+ 0.01, lon = 6.1439 - 0.01), c(lat = 46.2037 - 
    0.005, lon = 6.1439 + 0.01), type = "osm")

mapLatLon <- openproj(map)

df <- data.frame("long" = c(6.08, 6.14),
                 "lat" = c(46.18, 46.203))

autoplot(mapLatLon) +
  geom_point(data= df, aes(x = long, y = lat))
```

The layer with geom_point is covering the open street map tile.

Comment: crosspost: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343879/geom-point-not-showing-open-street-map-below-with-autoplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to transform the projection to the WGS84, so that they are in the same projection as my data.

Before plotting I had to run the code:

```
 map.latlon <- openproj(map, 
                      projection = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
```